# Странные ответы от CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь познать как работает casperjs на простом примере, а именно: пытаюсь зайти на сайт переводчика [bing](https://www.bing.com/translator) и перевести некую фразу, однако не могу понять, почему иногда он возвращает ответ, а иногда нет =\
Может кто-то с таким сталкивался? Или есть гуру этой библиотеки, которые знают где я накосячил, а я 100% накосячил.

```js
//System Vars
var system = require('system'),
    casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }),
    format = require('utils').format;

//Local Vars
var source = casper.cli.get('source') || 'en',
    target = casper.cli.get('target'),
    data = casper.cli.get(0),
    url = format('http://www.bing.com/translator?from=%s&to=%s', source, target),
    result;

//CasperJS options
casper.options.waitTimeout = 20000;


if (!target) {
    casper.warn('The --target option is mandatory.').exit(1);
}

casper.start(url, function() {
    console.log('Page Loaded');
})

casper.waitForSelector('#srcText', function() {

    var text = JSON.parse(atob(data)).join('\n');
    var rows_count = JSON.parse(atob(data)).length - 1;

    this.sendKeys('#srcText', text);
    
    this.then(function() {
        this.click('#TranslateButton');
        this.waitForSelector('div[paragraphname="paragraph'+rows_count+'"]', function() {
            listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
                var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#destText > div');
                return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
                    return node.textContent;
                });
            });
            this.echo(JSON.stringify(listItems));
        });
    });


});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась путем замены sendKeys на fillSelectors

Comment: Вы можете выбрать свой ответ принятым. Это поможет найти решение другим пользователям с подобной проблемой

Comment: Да я в курсе, мне пишет, что могу только завтра. Вот жду)